# How to choose a certain position to split a string by "_"?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string like this `'00004079_20150427_5_169_192_114.npz'`, and I want to split it into this `['00004079_20150427_5', '169_192_114.npz']`.

I tried the Python string `split()` method:

```py
a = '00004079_20150427_5_169_192_114.nii.npz'
a.split("_", 3)
```

but it returned this:

```
['00004079', '20150427', '5', '169_192_114.nii.npz']
```

How can I split this into 2 parts by the third `"_"` appearance?

I also tried this:

```py
reg = ".*\_.*\_.\_"
re.split(reg, a)
```

but it returns:

```
['', '169_192_114.nii.npz']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the string based on the delimiter `_` upto 3 times and then join back everything except the last value

```
>>> *start, end = s.split('_', 3)
>>> start = '_'.join(start)
>>> 
>>> start
'00004079_20150427_5'
>>> end
'169_192_114.npz'
```

For **python2**, you can follow this instead

```
>>> lst = s.split('_', 3)
>>> end = lst.pop()
>>> start = '_'.join(lst)
>>> 
>>> start
'00004079_20150427_5'
>>> end
'169_192_114.npz'
```

Comment: Thanks! One additional question, why do you add `*` in front of `start`,  is it a pointer or something like that?

Comment: This is called list unpacking. `*a, b = [1, 2, 3]` would make the last element `3` to be assigned to `b` and the rest of the list `[1, 2]` to be assigned `a`. Check https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations for more details

Answer (score 1):

One of possible approaches (if going with regex):

```
import re

s = '00004079_20150427_5_169_192_114.nii.npz'
res = re.search(r'^((?:[^_]+_){2}[^_]+)_(.+)', s)
print(res.groups())
```

The output:

```
('00004079_20150427_5', '169_192_114.nii.npz')
```